# How to organize OAuth 2 Password grant with multiple user types?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I clearly understand how OAuth 2 works but stuck with the situation when we have multiple user types.

[Password grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) requires the following parameters:

```
grant_type
     REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "password".

username
     REQUIRED.  The resource owner username.

password
     REQUIRED.  The resource owner password.

scope
     OPTIONAL.  The scope of the access request
```

But what if I want to authorize as a customer? Customers have usernames and passwords too, but they are different from users and stored in a separate DB table.

Create new non-standard **grant_type** or add some non-standard additional parameters like `user_type`?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new grant type doesn't make sense. I am currently working on OAuth2.o as well and We provide support for custom attributes for all these kind of things. For your use case, this is a classic case of Authorization based on role. So my support is for later option as it is flexible and tomorrow if you want sub roles to be supported you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you may use `scope` for this purpose. Whenever a customer app is used, it would include e.g. the `scope` value `customer` in the list of requested scopes, thus the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server would know where to check username/password.